# Why Github doest load all project files to the folder(For MAC users)

Tags: github

Everyone
I wanted to ask , why github doesn't work as it meant to be. When i clone the project it doesn't show all files and all codes inside it.But when i do "git push" it doesn't show any error and loads the whole project.I am using "ssh" in order to load.

When i open the cloning project it shows ViewController in red with full of empty spaces.
What can be a problem? It is first time i have encountered with this problem.

I have used "git push -u origin main" function in the end.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing - cloning means copying *from* Github, and pushing means copying *to* Github, so which one is it that is not working?

Comment: @IMSoP I mean i push project and when i clone it from there i confront this issue,cloning works for checking everything right,but it shows there is a problem.

Comment: Have you committed anything to your repository before pushing? I am not referring to editing files in the folder, but using `git add` and `git commit` to save the changes to your local repository.

Comment: @AliSamji   I have used git add . and git commit "first commit" in the beginning.  After these i have applied "git remote rename origin destination".

Comment: You said "cloning works for checking everything right, but it shows there is a problem". So are you getting an error message? If so, can you include it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if the project that you are cloning (from GitHub) has a `.gitmodules` in it.
That would explain why some folders (the ones listed in the `.gitmodules` file) are still empty after a clone.

Try and clone your repository again (in a new folder) with:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com/<aUser>/<aRepo>
```

---

The other option is, in your local repository that you have pushed, you have nested git subrepositories: look for `.git/` subfolder anywhere in your local repo folder (beside the very top folder, since it does include the expected local Git structure in `.git/`)

Such nested repositories would not be added, committed/pushed. Only a reference to their top SHA1 would be recorded, leaving GitHub displaying their folders as empty, gray with a white arrow.

You would need to:

- remove the `.git/` locally (in those nested subfolder),
- `git rm --cached afolder` (no trailing `/`: do that for each folder which had a `.git`)
- add everything,
- commit and push again.

Comment: how to check gitmodues inside the project?

Comment: @Allahverdi "check"? See if there is a `.gitmodules` file in your main repository: it will give you all the information about the submodules to be checked out.

Comment: no there is not any .gitmodules file.It has never been in my projects.

Comment: @Allahverdi Do you see gray folders with a white arrow on GitHub? I have edited my answer.

Comment: yes i see but it is as always,I think main issue is in renaming origin to destination.

Comment: @Allahverdi No: if you see gray folder, the issue is "nested Git repository": my answer address that.

Comment: But i dont see any :(

Answer (score -1):

I have loaded projects with the "git destination" while it must be "git origin" and in the end we must use "git push origin master"